# LogMeIn Host Computer

Tags: remote-access, logmein

If my host computer is powered off, is there a way to power it back on from a remote location using LogMeIn?

Answer (score 3):

Wake on Lan is the way to go.  Read the information in the link below.

http://community.logmeinrescue.com/t5/Free/Wake-on-LAN/td-p/31061

Comment: It's important to note that Wake-on-LAN does **not** wake up shutdown PCs.

Comment: @Tobias - Depending on the exact hardware, machines can in fact be powered on over LAN (even without dedicated out-of-band management hardware)

Comment: @chipShot It'd be great if you explained/summarized in your answer what the link actually said about WOL and LogMeIn - we shouldn't just link to other websites here. Welcome to SU, btw!

Comment: @Shinrai Agreed, my Dell does that fairly well.

Comment: @slhck Appreciate the welcome.  On a side note the answer below me as well just links to an outside site.  I just was doing as I have seen elsewhere on SU.

Comment: @chipShot I know, please don't feel offended! :) Here's the discussion about the whole thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @slhck No worries!

Comment: @Tobias: It does.  As long as the power chord is connected the PSU, WoL can wake up all the machines and servers I have, and I have one from 2000.  WoL  keeps the NIC powered, even when the machine is shut down, and it can wake up the machine from the S5 (OFF) power state.

Comment: @Tobias Plutat: what do you mean by: "It's important to note that Wake-on-LAN does not wake up shutdown PCs"? That's exactly what WoL does...

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with just LogMeIn, you need something like WOL (Wake On LAN).

> [Can you boot your computer through Log Me In? - LogMeIn Community Forums](http://community.logmein.com/t5/Miscellaneous-Offtopic/Can-you-boot-your-computer-through-Log-Me-In/td-p/23402)

Comment: This is no longer true. You can wake a PC from S3 (sleep), S4 (hibernate) and S5 (shut down) perfectly easily using LogMeIn's Wake on LAN functionality. I've been using it for nearly 2 years now. https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/Webhelp/CentralUserGuide/LogMeIn/t_host_preferences_WakeonLAN.html